# Cmake issue during MySQL 8.0.30 compilation

Tags: mysql, cmake, compiler-errors, ninja

I want to build `MySQL 8.0.30` but it fails with the following error:

> [3199/3567] Linking CXX executable
> runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe FAILED:
> runtime_output_directory/mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe cmd.exe /C "cd .
> && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe
> --intdir=router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir
> --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1433~1.316\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\library_file.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\main.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\plugin_info_app.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\plugin.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir_*_*_*_*\versioninfo_exe.rc.res
> /out:runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe
> /implib:router\src\plugin_info\src\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.lib
> /pdb:runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.pdb /version:0.0
> /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console
> ws2_32.lib  router\src\harness\src\harness-library.lib
> archive_output_directory\mysys.lib
> archive_output_directory\strings.lib
> archive_output_directory\mysys.lib
> archive_output_directory\strings.lib
> archive_output_directory\mytime.lib  archive_output_directory\zlib.lib
> archive_output_directory\zstd.lib  crypt32.lib  shlwapi.lib
> ws2_32.lib
> C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libsslMTd.lib
> C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libcryptoMTd.lib
> crypt32.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
> shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
> && cd ." LINK Pass 1: command
> "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1433~1.316\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\library_file.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\main.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\plugin_info_app.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir\plugin.cc.obj
> router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir_*_*_*_*\versioninfo_exe.rc.res
> /out:runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe
> /implib:router\src\plugin_info\src\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.lib
> /pdb:runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.pdb /version:0.0
> /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console
> ws2_32.lib router\src\harness\src\harness-library.lib
> archive_output_directory\mysys.lib
> archive_output_directory\strings.lib
> archive_output_directory\mysys.lib
> archive_output_directory\strings.lib
> archive_output_directory\mytime.lib archive_output_directory\zlib.lib
> archive_output_directory\zstd.lib crypt32.lib shlwapi.lib ws2_32.lib
> C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libsslMTd.lib
> C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libcryptoMTd.lib
> crypt32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib
> ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST
> /MANIFESTFILE:router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir/intermediate.manifest router\src\plugin_info\src\CMakeFiles\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.dir/manifest.res"
> failed (exit code 1169) with the following output:
> harness-library.lib(harness-library.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int
> __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits >::pubsync(void)" (?pubsync@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHXZ)
> already defined in plugin_info_app.cc.obj
> harness-library.lib(harness-library.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int
> __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHD@Z)
> already defined in plugin_info_app.cc.obj
> harness-library.lib(harness-library.dll) : error LNK2005: "public:
> __int64 __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits >::sputn(char const *,__int64)"
> (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA_JPEBD_J@Z)
> already defined in plugin_info_app.cc.obj
> runtime_output_directory\mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe : fatal error
> LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found [3208/3567]
> Linking CXX executable runtime_output_directory\mysqld.exe ninja:
> build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
> C:\mysql-8.0.30\build>

I use this command to build `MySQL:`

```
cmake -H. -B"C:\\mysql-8.0.30\\build" -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\\MySQL\\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\\debug" -DLINK_STATIC_RUNTIME_LIBRARIES=1 -DFORCE_INSOURCE_BUILD=1 -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST="C:\\Boost" -DWITH_SSL="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug" -DOPENSSL_LIBRARY="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libsslMTd.lib" -DCRYPTO_LIBRARY="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1q\static\x64\debug\lib\libcryptoMTd.lib" -G "Ninja"
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by adding the following option: `-DWITH_ROUTER=OFF` to my command. Now, it compiles without issues. The issue is resolved.